# one-to-many field in Django

Tags: python, django

I've got this class:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    dollar_amount = models.FloatField()
    item_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

I'm trying to make it so that 'product' has a one to many field. In other words, whenever I am adding a new item in django's default admin page. I want to be able to have the option of putting multiple 'product' for the same dollar amount and item number.

In response to Hedde van der Heide's comment. Would this be how you implement this?

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Order)
    dollar_amount = models.FloatField()
    item_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    order_product = models.CharField(max_length =256)
    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.order_product
```

Comment: Have a look at the solutions out there and how they work they will give you some hints. Also the poll [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) by Django gives you an idea how to work with manytomany and foreignkey relationships. Above all write your objects down on a piece of paper to visualize the workflow, it helps!

Comment: Is what I am asking correct in that I am wanting a one-to-many field? Or would that be a many-to-many field? Or is that a many-to-one field?

Comment: You probably want neither and instead create an in between model, e.g. `Order` (holds a fk to a `Customer` and `Payment`), `OrderItem` (holds the quantity and fks to Product and Order) and `Product`. This will allow for `order.orderitem_set.all` reference. Disclaimer: It all depends on the solution that fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

No, your edit is incorrect. That would imply a purchase order could belong to many orders and vice versa, which makes no sense. You want a simple ForeignKey from PurchaseOrder to Order.